# Reading from .docx file results in a newline though the file is not just a newline

Tags: python, file, python-docx, paragraph

I have some text stored in a `.docx` file:

```
Dear xx01xx,

    Thank you for coming to my birthday party. I’m glad you came. Thanks for the xx02xx present!

            Your best friend,
                Alan Bagel

If you want to see my token of appreciation for your coming, please go to xx03xx street.
```

Now when I try to read text from it:

```py
import docx

template = docx.Document("...")
for paragraph in template.paragraphs:
    print(paragraph.text)
```

The result is just a newline! Is the support for `.docx` files so limited it can be confused by the smaller font size on the file line?

Comment: If text is in a table even a table with no borders then paragraph.text won't get it. Try to iterate over template.tables.

Comment: @CodeMonkey No data is in tables.

Comment: Check revision status. `python-docx` won't pick up paragraphs in unaccepted revisions. Use `print(template._element)` to view the XML and see if any elements are "wrapping" paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even though you created a `.docx` file, you forgot to save it, thus `python-docx` not being able to read it.